# Can't add NSLayoutConstraints programmatically in Swift (no effect)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've created a custom UIView subclass in Swift with a corresponding `.xib` file but am having trouble adding Auto Layout constraints during initialization. The view itself loads just fine, but adding layout constraints seems to have no effect on the view's layout, regardless of whether I add these constraints within `init` or `viewDidMoveToSuperview` or `viewDidMoveToWindow`, and even if I call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` / `layoutIfNeeded()` immediately after.

I can do this quite easily in Objective-C, so hopefully this is a very simple fix, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var isLoading = false

class CustomSubview: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private lazy var view: UIView! = { [unowned self] in
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nibName = String(CustomSubview.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }()

    private func setup() {
        if (isLoading) {
            return
        }

        isLoading = true
//        self.view.frame = self.bounds // this works but I want to use Auto Layout
//        self.view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight] // this works but I want to use Auto Layout
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // no effect
        addSubview(self.view)
        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("view", self.view))
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(horizontalConstraints) // this seems to do nothing
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(verticalConstraints) // this seems to do nothing
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        isLoading = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your `view` to false?

Comment: Yup, and that doesn't seem to have any effect either. (now added above)

Comment: 'addSubview(self.view)' looks strange to me.

Comment: Hi @Anupam: 'self.view' is actually a lazily instantiated private variable that instantiates the view from the nib.

Comment: You have to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your `view` (like Anupam said, I don't think naming your view `view` is good btw) to false. Not the `UIView` itself.

Comment: @Eendje That seems to have done it! But I am still having issue with an aspect ratio constraint (which I omitted from the original question for clarity & focus). Any idea why that one constraint still doesn't seem to be working? A little outside of scope so I may post as a separate SO question.

Comment: And @Eendje can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark as correct?

Comment: And re: Aspect ratio, I was mistakenly updating the value of the NSLayoutConstraint's constant rather than replacing the entire NSLayoutConstraint with an updated constraint with the correct multiplier value.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of aspect ratio constraint you want? Maybe I can hep you out.

Comment: Hi @Eendje – It was the same mistake that I've made before, which is that you can't edit the value of the the multiplier in an NSLayoutConstraint after it's been made. Instead, you just have to create a brand new NSLayoutConstraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reworked your class a bit to make it look a bit cleaner. I've omitted the loading `Bool`. Also I have no experience in creating views from a XIB file I pretty much left it almost untouched.

```
var isLoading = false

class CustomSubview: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    private lazy var customView: UIView = {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nibName = String(CustomSubview.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let customView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return customView
    }()

    private func setup() {
        if (isLoading) {
            return
        }

        isLoading = true
        addSubview(self.customView)
        let views = ["customView": customView]

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[customView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[customView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        isLoading = false
    }
}
```

As for your aspect ratio constraint, you can set multiple constraint for your aspect ratio and set the `active` of those to `true` / `false` to switch between them.

Comment: I added `isLoading` back in, as `nib.instantiateWithOwner(_, options:)` calls `init?(coder:)`, leading to an infinite loop.